# the limit of a sequence to another sequence indeterminate form

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, indeterminate-forms

[image]

[image]

I am trying to solve this limit question...I have tried to take the natural log of an^(bn), but somehow ended up with infinity times infinity. Is there any way to this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hint: what happens when you have $x^r$, $x<1, r \to \infty$?

Comment: Also, when taking the natural logarithm: you end up with "$\infty\times (-\infty)$," which is not indeterminate: it gives divergence to $-\infty$. Which does allow you to conclude, since "$e^{-\infty} = 0$" (this is handwavy, but can be easily made formal; the point being, there is no indeterminate form here.)

Comment: Ah...I had my lecture notes written down ∞×(−∞) as indeterminate and so was stuck. Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once $n$ is large enough, $b_n > 1$ and $\lvert a_n\rvert  < 1$ so that

$$\lvert a_n^{b_n} \rvert = \lvert a_n\rvert^{b_n} < \lvert a_n\rvert$$

which converges to zero.

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(a_n^{b_n})=
\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n\log a_n=-\infty
$$